# How to creat an Instance in javaml with TestData?

Tags: java, machine-learning, knn

The small sample of my problem is in the [repo](https://github.com/salman-/javaml-knn).

I have the below dataset in a `.data` file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,Action
0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Up"
2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,"Left"
4,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Left"
4,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Up"
4,4,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,"Up"
8,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,"Left"
```

The dataset has 16 `int` features and the last column is `String`. I want to use the first 16 features to predict the last column using `knn`.

I have trained my model successfully based on [this link](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/content/classification-basics).

```
        knn = new KNearestNeighbors(5);
        knn.buildClassifier(data);
```

But now, i need to ***Test*** my model. So, the format of the TestData is, 16 integer numbers, and i expect that the `knn` model ***predicts*** the action.

Sample Test Data is:

```
4,4,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
```

based on the code i need to have an object of `Instance` ***interface*** from `net.sf.javaml.core.Instance`, but the problem is:

***i am wondering how to create such instance?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can simply use [SparseInstance](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.7/net/sf/javaml/core/SparseInstance.html) method which asks for an array of Doubles. If, you convert your TestData to `Double`, then it will be very easy:

```
double[] testData = {32,16,8,2,16,8,2,2,8,2,0,0,0,0,0,0};
Instance inst=new SparseInstance(testData);
Object predictedClassValue = knn.classify(inst);
System.out.println("Result is: "+predictedClassValue);
```

I tried the above code on your repo, and it gives me:

```
Result is: Left
```